# python accessing objects attributes inside of another object

Tags: python

I am using an sdk to call apis to a third party. However I want to encapsulate the object that returns from those sdk calls in my own class, so that I can add logic around serialization, etc.

Note that the sdk is provided by the third party so I don't want to play around with their object definitions.

So effectively I want to do something like:

```
object = sdk.api_call()
return MyClass(object)
```

where MyClass is defined as:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, sdk_object):
         self.sdk_object = sdk_object

    def serialize(self):
        #my own custom logic here
```

However, I still want to be able to access all the attributes and functions of the sdk_object without having to go through myclass_instance.sdk_object.attribute_name. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you elaborate...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, how about:

```
sdk_object = myclass_instance.sdk_object
sdl_object.attribute_name = 10
```

Is that what do you mean?

Comment: I would prefer for all the attributes to be accessible via myclass_instance directly. However, I will have to access it this way if that's not possible.

Comment: Why not use inheritance then?

Comment: Yes I was thinking that -- I already have my model class inheriting from another object but I can prob use multiple inheritance